# Carriage return to file on bash

Tags: linux, bash, echo, carriage-return

I'm trying to redirect a echo to file but the carriage returns(\r) are inserted as **^M**. This is the command I'm using

```
echo -e "<VirtualHost *:80>
                \r  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
                \r  ServerName site
                \r  ServerAlias site
                \r  ErrorLog \"/var/log/apache2/html-error.log\"
                \r  LogFormat \"%t<>%u<>%h<>%O<>%T<>%>s<>%{Referer}i<>%r<>%{User-Agent}i\" combined
                \r  CustomLog \"/var/log/apache2/html-access.log\" combined
                \r  RewriteEngine on
                \r  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site
                \r  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
                \r</VirtualHost>\n" > teste.txt
```

This is what it looks in the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ^M  DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp
                ^M  ServerName iqnus.bvloja.com
                ^M  ServerAlias iqnus.bvloja.com
                ^M  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/webapp-error.log"
                ^M  LogFormat "%t<>%u<>%h<>%O<>%T<>%>s<>%{Referer}i<>%r<>%{User-Agent}i" combined
                ^M  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/webapp-access.log" combined
                ^M  RewriteEngine on
                ^M  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =iqnus.bvloja.com
                ^M  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
                ^M</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: have you tried using printf instead of echo? and use \n instead of \r

Comment: `^M` is how whatever you are viewing your file with represents the carriage returns. Do you *want* carriage returns? You don't need anything special if you simply want a multi-line file; the newlines inside the double quotes are treated literally and written to the file.

Comment: More typically correct is `printf '%s\n' 'first line' 'second line'` -- that'll create a UNIX text file; only LFs, no CRs anywhere. CRLF sequences are a Windows thing; you don't want them on UNIXy systems.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for `\n` instead of `\r`. A new line on a non-Windows machine would be just `\n`, or if you're on Windows it would be `\r\n`.

Answer (score -2):

the -e flag enables the interpretation of backslash escapes.
Just use echo instead of echo -e.

Comment: `\r` _is_ a backslash escape.

Comment: Mind, `echo -e` is inherently POSIX-noncompliant (and in bash it can be turned off entirely at runtime such that it just writes `-e` to output; the right thing is to use `printf '%b\n' ...` instead of `echo -e '...'`) -- but that's a separate discussion.